# How can I detect what browser my Silverlight application is running in?

Tags: silverlight, browser-detection

I need to know because I have to run external (popup) features that use ActiveX (which I can't help).  I want to disable (or hide) buttons that activate these features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.UserAgent?

Comment: Yeah, I just found that. O.o  I've been looking for days, and so I post here, and lo and behold I find it.  Murphy is working hard today. **sigh**

Comment: tell me about it...happens all the time.